# Subgroup of translation group

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand factor (quotient) groups and I thought maybe constructing my own example would help me.

Let $H_{\lambda} = \lambda \mathbb{Z}$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ be a subgroup of the the 1-dimensional translation group $T$. Since $T$ is abelian then $H_\lambda$ is an invariant subgroup. Then consider the factor group $K_\lambda = T/H_\lambda$.

Does $K_\lambda$ basically contain actions that say translate by $(x+m\lambda)$ for $x \in T$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ or is that conclusion incorrect?

I am concluding this because the elements of $K_\lambda$ are $xH_{\lambda}$ for $x \in T$.

Comment: Maybe the action is not well-defined. If your action is for $\lambda$-periodic function, action of factor group is still well-defined, but in general, there is no reason that factor group inherits well-defined action. However, your reasoning to get the factor group is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have some confusion around what the elements of $K_{\lambda}$ are.

A quotient (factor) group $G/N$ of a group $G$ by a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is by definition a bunch of certain subsets of $G$, called cosets, endowed with a group operation. These cosets are defined as the sets $xN = \{ xn : n \in N \}$.

You can show that for any subgroup $H$ (not necessarily normal) that these cosets form a partition of $G$: for any $x,y \in G$, either $xH = yH$ or $xH \cap yH = \emptyset$, and $G$ is the union of all cosets. When a subgroup $N$ is normal, by defining a product on these subsets by $xN \cdot yN = xyN$, these subsets form a group.

Saying “Does $K_{\lambda}$ basically contain actions” doesn’t really make sense: $K_{\lambda}$ contains collections of actions. It is true however, that each subset of actions in $K_{\lambda}$ can be described as $\{ x + m\lambda \}_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}$ for a fixed $x$. This is because two elements $a,b$ are in the same coset if and only if $a - b \in N$.

Comment: I have some more clarity now, but just to reiterate: Each member of $K_\lambda$ is a set $xH_\lambda = \{x + m\lambda : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, but happens if $x=n\lambda, \ n\in \mathbb{Z}$ do we have $n\lambda H_\lambda= H_\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, since then $xH_{\lambda} := \{ n\lambda + m\lambda : m \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{ (n + m)\lambda : m \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{ k\lambda : k \in \mathbb{Z} \} = H_{\lambda}$